# vb.net combobox_drop down error (There is no row at position 0)

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Private Sub client_name_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles client_name.DropDown

    Dim cmd = New SQLiteCommand("SELECT Name FROM client WHERE Type = 'Recipient'", cn)
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cn.Open()
    End If
    Dim adapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    client_name.DataSource = table
    client_name.DisplayMember = "Name"
    client_name.Refresh()

End Sub
```

I added this code to get the latest Recipient from the db table named Client.

But when I dropdown the combo box, it display error: "There is no row at position 0" after this error the combobox display the data from database.

[image]

But every time I click this display an error first. How to remove the error?

Comment: I don't see how that message could be displayed by that code. There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: By the way, you should learn how to manage ADO.NET objects. You are opening a connection and not closing it, which is bad. It's worse though, given that there's no point opening it the first place, given that `Fill` will open it for you if required, then close it for you if it was opened. It's worse still though, because you should be creating the connection object in that code, just as you are the data adapter. All ADO.NET objects, including connections, should be as short-lived as possible.

Comment: It seems odd that you would populate and repopulate the `ComboBox` every time the user drops down the list. Are you really expecting the list the change so frequently?

Comment: Even if you're going to set the `DataSource` over and over, there's no point setting the `DisplayMember` over and over. `DisplayMember` should be set before `DataSource` too. Set the `DisplayMember` in the designer or once when the form loads, then just set the `DataSource` each time. The `Refresh` would also be pointless, I would think, although I'd have to test to be sure.

Comment: Every dropdown selection repopulate the data from database its seems to be a issue for this error message. kindly check dropdown selection event is required. even handler use selected changed instead of dropdown if possible to change the event.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I mentioned refreshing the ComboBox in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444616/vb-net-combobox-data-not-updating) in the DropDown event along with a suggestion for a better solution. It is not clear if other users might be adding rows to the client table at the same time so I suggested updating the dropdown list before displaying it.

Comment: The database is being hit on the UI thread, connections aren't being disposed properly, simple errors are misunderstood... You guys are very nice to try to help, but judging by these two questions, it seems like a lost cause.